# Variable "Variables" in Javascript - Undefined

Tags: javascript, json

JSON:

```
var promiseObj = {
"physical": [],
"virtual": []
}
var config = {
"Environments": [
"LH5",
"LH8",
"AMS"
],
 "Clusters": {
    "LH5": 4,
    "LH8": 4,
    "AMS": 4
}
};
```

So I am trying to set different promise objects based on the environments and the clusters in the given JSON object above.

```
for (var i = 0; i < config.Environments.length; i++) { 
    promiseObj.physical[config.Environments[i]][config.Clusters[config.Environments[i]]] = $http.get('URL').success(function(data) {
    //Successful stuff here 
});

}
```

However when performing this for loop I get the following error:

```
promiseObj.physical[config.Environments[i]] is undefined
```

Could someone shed some light into why this is returning undefined, when the object is clearly defined at the start of the document?

Comment: `promiseObj.physical = [];` therefore `promiseObj.physical[anything]` will be undefined. It doesn't matter what `config.Environments[i]` returns because the `physical` array is empty.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: Create those keys instead of only trying to access them.

Comment: Since `config.Environments[i]` is a `string`, `promiseObj.physical[string]` has wrong syntax (array index cannot be a `string`

Comment: I would first break that long expression into shorter expressions using local variables. Eg `var envname = config.Environments[i];` instead of repeating that expression. It makes it easier to read. Then double-check that you really want the multiple levels of nesting in the data structure that the code expects (but currently fails because you can't index `undefined`).

Comment: Thanks everyone - learnt a lot :D

Comment: @CoreyOgburn - please mark yours as the answer if you want the rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `physical` is an empty array, any and all keys within it are `undefined`. You need to prime them the first time you use them:

```
if (typeof promiseObj.physical[config.Environments[i]] == 'undefined') {
    promiseObj.physical[config.Environments[i]] = {};  // or [], whichever you want
}
promiseObj.physical[config.Environments[i]][config.Clusters[config.Environments[i]]] = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `physical` as an array and then accessing it as an object, so you're trying to access a property that can't exist.
Try declaring `physical` as follows:

```
"physical": {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `promiseObj.physical[]` is an empty array, you have to initialize the index you want before:

```
for (var i = 0; i < config.Environments.length; i++) { 
    if(!promiseObj.physical[config.Environments[i]]) promiseObj.physical[config.Environments[i]] = {}; // Initialize it
    promiseObj.physical[config.Environments[i]][config.Clusters[config.Environments[i]]] = $http.get('URL').success(function(data) {
    //Successful stuff here 
    });

}
```